# jquery not working in mobile environment: some links are not changing when I open in Android browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery

I am trying to open a site in Android, all the codes are working for desktop but some links are not changing when I open in Android browser.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('a').each(function(i,link){
        var reg = /(http:\/\/example.com\/)(.*)/
        var newlink = link.href.replace(reg, 'http://m.example.com/$2')
        link.href = newlink;

    });

});
```

I am replacing all the links in a webpage. is there any different code need to implement for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to change the href using jquery attr , use this to refer the object

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

       $('a').each(function(){
         var reg = /(http:\/\/example.com\/)(.*)/
         var href = $(this).attr("href");
         var newlink = href.replace(reg, 'http://m.example.com/$2');

         $(this).attr("href",newlink);

       });

});
```